# When to return from a function?

Tags: c++, function, return-type

Sorry in advance if the question sounds naive. I am writing a simple bool function to check if all digits of a  number are same. The following works, however the one after, gives me an error of

```
17:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

What I am doing wrong with the second one?

Working:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

using namespace std;

bool samedigits (int number){
    bool result = true;
    std::string snumber = to_string (number);
    for (int i=0; i < snumber.size(); i++){
        if (snumber[i] != snumber[0]){
            result = result and false;
            break;
        }   
    }
    return result; 
}

int main()
{
    cout << samedigits (666);
    return 0;
}
```

Non working:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

using namespace std;

bool samedigits (int number){
    
    std::string snumber = to_string (number);
    for (int i=0; i < snumber.size(); i++){
        if (snumber[i] != snumber[0]){
            return false;
            break;
        }   
        return true;
    }
    
}

int main()
{
    cout << samedigits (666);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `snumber` is empty, how many times does `for (int i=0; i < snumber.size(); i++)` run?  If the loop never runs, does the function ever reach a `return` statement? Also think on what use is a for loop that returns on ever iteration of the loop.

Comment: The codes are not equivalent. The loop in the second snippet is useless.

Comment: The second code snippet will always return in the first loop iteration  (and since `snumber[0]` is equal to itself, will always return `true`.   The warning is a bit spurious, but compilers tend to get false positives in identifying non-reachable code when the structure is a bit convoluted as your is.   In the first `result = result and false` has the same effect as `result = false`.

Comment: Are you aware that the `break` in the second example is useless (dead code)?

Comment: @JaMiT I do not think it is totally useless as it saves time. Imagine the string is too long, the first instance it finds a different digit it stops the loop

Comment: @HomayounGhojavand the string can't be too long since the range of `int` is limited. You don't even need to convert to string, just take the digits and return early if there's a different digit. If you convert to string then you have to loop through all the digits in the converting function

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `result = result and false;` is usually written `result = false;`. <g>

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is incorrect, you are only checking if the first character is equal to itself, and returning true for every input. Instead, you should move the `return true` outside the loop, so that you check all the characters first.

---

Unfortunately, the warning is a false positive. The compiler fails to realize that `std::to_string` is guaranteed to return a non-empty string when passed an `int`. This means that the `for` loop body will be entered, and the function will return a value.

Comment: If I move the ```return true``` out of the loop then it will always return true when the for loop is finished. Am I missing something?

Comment: What can you say about the string if the for loop finishes without hitting the if condition?

Comment: I think I would not call the warning a "false positive" since your analysis relies on information outside the function. I'd say it is a true positive, but can be proven irrelevant. I don't know if there is a good term for that, though. :( Maybe "technical positive"? "Irrelevant positive"? Meh, I guess leave it for now, and consider this comment an invitation for people to think of a better term.

Comment: @JaMiT Hmm, I think "false positive" is the right term. Not that I'm suggesting the compiler should ever be expected to get this right, but the warning is *still* wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right. There is a code path in your second snippet that won't return.

```
for (int i=0; i < snumber.size(); i++){
```

Here, the `std::string` size function can return `0` according to its contract. When it does happen, then your function won't enter the loop. After that, you exit the function without returning.

Comment: Can't happen, but the compiler can't see that.

Answer (score 0):

The second version of your function (combined with some information obtained via comments) indicates a misunderstanding of what `return` does. The second version would work (here is the misunderstanding) if a `return` statement were to simply store the indicated value for use when the function eventually ends. However, this is not how `return` works. A `return` statement stores the indicated value for use when the function ends **and immediately ends the function**. In the second version of your function, the `for` statement might as well be an `if` and the `break` is never executed as it comes right after a `return`.

---

To demonstrate, let's do a code walk-through for a call to `samedigits(123)`.

```
bool samedigits (int number){
```

As we enter the function, `number` is set to `123`.

```
std::string snumber = to_string (number);
```

The string `snumber` is set to `"123"`.

```
for (int i=0; i < snumber.size(); i++){
```

The loop initializes by setting `i` to `0` then checks if `0 < 3` (the size of `snumber` is 3). This is true, so we enter the loop. Note that the result of entering the loop depends only on `snumber` not being empty.

```
    if (snumber[i] != snumber[0]){
```

We check to see if `snumber[0]` does not equal `snumber[0]`. This is a bit trivial, but the computer is willing to do it. The result, of course, is false (independent of what the input was – this part might be more interesting if the loop started at `1` instead of `0`). So skip to the statement after the `if`.

```
    return true;
```

The function *immediately* ends, returning `true`.

And that's it. There is no second iteration of the loop. No other code is executed during this function call. Since `to_string` never returns an empty string, the second version of your function is functionally equivalent to the following:

```
bool samedigits (int /*number*/){
    return true;
    // Execution ends with the return statement, so nothing after
    // this comment ever executes.
    std::cout << "This is dead code. It will never execute.\n";
    std::cout << "You will never see this output.\n";
}
```

---

To fix the second version, you need to `return` inside the loop *only* when the `if` condition is true. Move `return true;` to be after the loop so that the loop can iterate multiple times. You do not want to end the function and tell the caller that all the digits are the same (which is what `return true;` does) until after you've checked all the digits. (If your loop finds a mismatch, execution will reach the `return false;` inside the loop. At that point, the function ends, so code after the loop has no effect on that function call.)

A smaller (cosmetic) fix is to get rid of the `break`. Suppose the loop did iterate enough times to find a mismatch. Execution would go into the `if` statement body and encounter `return false`. At that point, not only is the loop stopped, but the function as a whole ends, before the `break` statement is seen. The `break` statement is dead code, meaning code that can never be executed. In order to get to the `break`, execution has to go through a `return`. Execution may arrive at a `return` statement, but it never goes *through* one.

Also, be sure to thank your compiler for finding this error, as it does point to a bug in your code. It's not the exact bug the compiler reported, but then again, compilers are not exactly the best thinkers in the world. :)